# Asyncio starts to hide errors

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm using asyncio with websockets and aiohttp for a Twitch API bot. Everything was fine, but at some point `asyncio` starts to hide errors and makes the code a brick.

After a while dealing with that, i realize that only happens on functions (and nested ones) awaited on `asyncio.gather()`.

If you see in the images, I try print an unresolved reference, at that point the thread is dead and no errors are throw.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/532653651689472024/570191503587147776/Screenshot_2.png

Also, is weird this part of the asyncio code (`asyncio/events.py`) depending of the type error, asyncio loops over that part a lot of times. I dont know if that matters.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/532653651689472024/570191514634944522/Screenshot_4.png

Furthermore, i tried to uninstall `asyncio` with pycharm and with `pip`. The code still accessing to `asyncio` i dont know where. i dont have virtual environments set. is there some way to uninstall manually and try to reinstall `asyncio` cleanly?

By the way, my app still working, is just the fact of no having clues when I miss something, making the progress freaking hard

Answer (score 0):

> If you see in the images, I try print an unresolved reference, at that
>   point the thread is dead and no errors are throw.

`asyncio.gather` runs several tasks simultaneously, and [by default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) propagates first exception any of tasks raised. Even if this exception didn't finish your program, it at least changed position where your interpreter is. And while other gathered tasks continue to run in background their exceptions can't be raised from the new point where your interpreter is currently on.

Exceptions occurred in tasks but not raised anywhere [are printed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#detect-never-retrieved-exceptions) as warnings "Task exception was never retrieved" when event loop is closed (usually at the very end of your program).

It's hard to say if this is exactly what happens in your case since you didn't provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Feel free to provide one to receive more precise answer.

> Furthermore, i tried to uninstall asyncio with pycharm and with pip.
>   The code still accessing to asyncio i dont know where. i dont have
>   virtual environments set. is there some way to uninstall manually and
>   try to reinstall asyncio cleanly?

`asyncio` is a part of the Python's [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/). This module can't be (or at least shouldn't be) (re/un)installed without (re/un)installing Python interpreter itself.

Comment: I tried do a mcve code, but it print tracebacks as usually. Then I tried to force errors on others proyects and prints tracebacks too. I guess some third party module that requires `asyncio` (`websockets`, `aiohttp`) is changing it at some point, but at this moment i dont find where.

About `asyncio` as standar module. I though that because docs are in the python docs itself. But on interpreter settings of Pycharm it appears in the third party modules list. Interesting.

Thanks for the hints, specially around `asyncio.gather()`, I really felt so stuck because python doesnt give me feedback